# Made a restricted user account for SSH login, I have some security questions

Tags: macos, security, unix, ssh, port

I made a very restricted account on my OSX machine so when I'm away from home (in school, library, parents place etc.) I can login and work on some coding via VIM.

I am just figuring out how to set up an SSH key, but it kind of makes it inconvenient for me to use keys to login because I will be logging in from different computers and it's an annoying step to have to configure each time.

I was reading online that leaving your SSH port (22) open isn't advisable unless it's super secured because bots/people may try to brute force it (I know you can change the default port, though it doesn't do a whole lot for security).

So, I'm wondering, would it be ok to set this user account up with a very long, complex password and completely forgo the SSH key? Or would this be a stupid thing to do.

edit: also, how exactly do I look at my logs to see if I have had any unauthorized connection attempts?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the port from 22 to something else is a good idea. Since port 22 is very common to try to crack, if you change it to another port, bots will have to scan for open ports. If you have port scan detection software installed, you can block their IP addresses before they get very far.

Using password authentication is not a "stupid" thing to do if you have a nice long password with lots of entropy, however it is not nearly as strong as, say a 1024+ bit RSA/DSA key and it will be much more guessable. Even if your password were 50 characters long, most likely it will be some sort of a phrase using dictionary words. This is not to say that you are definitely going to get hacked, but the probability of it happening with password authentication is greater than public key authentication. You could also greatly increase security by adding two-factor authentication with something like OTP.

To check for failed login attempts I believe the log file for Macs is `/var/log/secure.log`. If not, look around in `/var/log`.